# kids book about dinosaurs and time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel, dinosaurs

A boy travels back in time to see this girl who looks after dinosaurs. I believe her name was Fern and she has ginger curly hair. I can't really remember anything else about the book, but I know he helped her look after dinosaurs. They wore tunics too, I think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Was it a picture book?  What time period did the boy travel _from_; contemporary time or the future?

Comment: Wild guess: (I didn't read it, so I do not know the names...) "Dinosaurs before Dark" by Mary Pope Osborne?